# Oozie Where does a custom EL function execute

Tags: oozie

I am writing a custom EL function which will be used in oozie workflows.

this custom function is just plain java code it doesn't contain any hadoop code.

My question is where will this EL function be executed at the time the workflow is running?

Will it execute my EL function on the Oozie node itself? or will it push my custom java code to one of the data nodes and execute it there?

Answer (score 0):

Oozie is a workflow scheduler system to manage jobs in Hadoop Cluster it self, which integrated with the rest of the Hadoop stack supporting several types of Hadoop jobs out of the box (such as Java map-reduce, Streaming map-reduce, Pig, Hive, Sqoop and Distcp) as well as system specific jobs (such as Java programs and shell scripts). [Source](http://oozie.apache.org/)

Which means if you submit a Job in Oozie, it will run in any of the available DataNode it self, even if your Oozie Service is configured in Datanode then it can run there as well.

For checking which Node the Job is processing, you have to check the same from JobTracker in Hadoop1 or Yarn in Hadoop2 which redirect the Process State to the Tasktracker node where the Job is being process

Answer (score 0):

Acording to [Apache Oozie: The Workflow Scheduler for Hadoop](https://books.google.es/books?id=HAY_CQAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=isbn:1449369774), page 177, it states:

> It is highly recommended that the new EL function be simple, fast and
>   robust. This is critical because Oozie executes the EL functions on
>   the Oozie server

So It will be executed on your Oozie node itself.